# Braces in angular appear for a second

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angular in my app and text appears for a second as this {{user.name}}, people told me to use ng-model, so am using `<span ng-model="user.name"></span>` but it's not showing anything. What should I do? Note: Beginner here.

Comment: For people marking the question as duplicate, please provide helpful thing instead, redirect me to the question where you say it's duplicate. Thank you

Comment: `ng-model` or `ng-value` on input field, `ng-bind` on span/div tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The span element is readonly.  You need an input type for two-way binding, which is what the ng-model directive is providing you.

Instead, you can utilize the [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) directive to hide the content prior to the template compiling.

Example:

```
<span ng-cloak>{{user.name}}</span>
```

Comment: So is this the recommended way in Angular projects?

Comment: I have to use this CSS class mentioned in this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak  ???

Comment: There is also a recommendation to use class="ng-cloak" .. what's the difference? And do I have to do css to hide it?